# Update multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables :

```
   Projects: ID - ProjectName - Areas - PaymentSystem- etc 
   project details : DetailsID - ProjectDetailName - ProjectDetailImage -ProjectID
```

i wrote this query to update those two tables  but i have error message when i execute this procedure

> Procedure Update_Project_Detail, Line 35
>   Invalid column name 'ID'.

:

```
  create proc Update_Project_Detail

   @projectname nvarchar(MAX),
   @area nvarchar(MAX),
   @paymentsystem nvarchar(MAX),
   @receivedDate date,
   @propertyClassification nvarchar(MAX),
   @projectImage nvarchar(MAX),
   @ProjectDetailName nvarchar(MAX),
    @ProjectDetailImage nvarchar(MAX),
    @projectid int

     as
     UPDATE Projects

       SET

       ProjectName =  @projectname,
       Areas = @area,
       PaymentSystem = @paymentsystem,
       ReceivedDate = @receivedDate,
       PropertyClassification = @propertyClassification,
       ProjectImage = @projectImage

      where 
       ID = @projectid

     UPDATE ProjectDetails

     SET 
      ProjectDetailName = @ProjectDetailName,
      ProjectDetailImage = @ProjectDetailImage

      where 
      ID = @projectid
```

Comment: ID should perhaps be PROJECTID in the final where clause.  (line 35)

Comment: id column doesn't exists in your table

Comment: Can you show the schema of the 2 tables? Agree with @JohnPasquet. Also the error is quite self explanatory. Probably didn't need to ask us here.

Comment: The error message is very clear.  You don't have the column ID.

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Comment: i updated the questions with tables column

Comment: What part of this is confusing? The error message states exactly...you don't have a column ID in ProjectDetails. It can't be stated more clearly than that.

Comment: This is a classic example of why it is horrible idea to have a column like ProjectID change names based on which table it resides in. It is always a ProjectID no matter what table it is in. The habit of using ID in one table and ProjectID in another a very bad design. I am actually surprised I have not seen an Aaron Bertrand article in his bad habit series on that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

invalid column used, See below for correct update statement:

```
UPDATE ProjectDetails
SET 
ProjectDetailName = @ProjectDetailName,
ProjectDetailImage = @ProjectDetailImage
where ProjectID= @projectid
```

Answer (score 3):

The "LINE 35" in the error statement clues you in.  Count down to line 35.  You will see this refers to your last where clause:  "ID = @projectid".

The error tells you this column does not exist.  Since this is the ProjectDetails table, I imagine you may have called this column "ProjectID" instead of "ID", which is what you used on the Projects table.

So, probably change the WHERE clause to **ProjectID = @projectid**.

Comment: you can edit your answer as he posted his data columns